# Performance em Consultas ao Banco de Dados MySql

Tags: php, mysql, desempenho

Qual a melhor opção em termos de performance? Eu fazer

```
select * from agenda, paciente where agenda.id_paciente = paciente.id_paciente
```

e pegar os dados juntos da agenda e paciente ou fazer primeiro

```
select * from agenda
```

e depois outro select dentro do loop

```
select * from paciente where id_paciente = agenda.id_paciente
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usar dois `SELECTS` separados faz sentido apenas se você for pegar dados de tabelas diferentes ou critérios muito variados a cada registro.

Cada vez que você faz uma *query* pelo PHP, é feito um novo pedido ao servidor de DB, que tem que fazer o planejamento e a execução dos dados. Enviando uma query só que seja enxuta (como um *join* simples), o planejamento é feito uma vez só e os resultados são processados de uma maneira mais otimizada pelo SGBD.

No exemplo dado, ficaria desta forma:

```
SELECT
   agenda.data,
   paciente.nome
   ... etc, especificando os campos um a um ...
FROM
   agenda
LEFT JOIN
   paciente ON agenda.id_paciente = paciente.id_paciente
```

Note estes pontos:

- Se você quer performance, e economia de dados, não deve usar o `*`, e sim definir os campos que vai usar, um a um.

  Não tem problema nenhum o uso do `*`, desde que você tenha uma razão real para usá-lo, o que não parece ser o caso do exemplo; porém, ao especificar os campos manualmente, você tem apenas processamento e tráfego dos dados que realmente necessita, e a ordem deles é previsível no retorno dos dados, mesmo que a tabela venha a ter novos campos no futuro.

  Além disso, como você tem mais de uma tabela em uso, ao digitar os campos você evita ambiguidades e enganos que podem passar despercebidos quando as duas tabelas tem campos de mesmo nome.
- se você especifica o tipo de *join* e usa a clausula ON, tem controle sobre a forma que o *join* é feito.

  Da forma que você fez com `where` funciona, mas aí você está dependendo do *planner* do DB entender o que você quer, e nem sempre é o melhor caminho se a complexidade da *query* verdadeira for grande.

Veja **[nesta postagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6448/70)** os tipos de JOIN essenciais para definir o melhor para o caso real.